# Use string format arguments in Android layout xml file

Tags: android

I have a string defined in my String.xml file that uses format arguments, i.e.:

```
<string name="myString">Hello %1$s.</string>
```

Is there a way to assign a value to the format argument in a layout xml file?  I have something like:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/myString"/>
```

I know I can do it in java, but is there a way to do it here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<strike>No, there is no means of applying a value to the format from a layout file -- only in Java. Sorry!</strike>

**UPDATE**: You can now use data binding for this — see the duplicate question.

Comment: I kinda thought that might be the case, but I was hoping otherwise.  Thanks!

Comment: Ouch. I really hoped to avoid having things like `my_string` and `my_string_colon`/`qmark`/`emark` etc. everywhere.

Comment: 7+ years later, is this answer still correct?

Comment: @GaryS.: You should be able to pull this off using the data binding framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes. Thank you! It's still Java, but it's probably the best way of doing what the OP wanted. Details: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Per what I studied, data binding expressions requires data so pure resources and operators does not work may data-binding is still not a very good solution.

Comment: It is possible now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38984088/3190931.

Answer (score -6):

For Example
In strings.xml
You have %d unread messages

In Your Java code
String message = getString(R.string.unread_messages, 10);

Comment: Please read the question. OP didnt want to set it in JAVA but in the layout file.

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling