# Can I use a String Resource in a String Resource in string.xml?

Tags: android, xml, string, resources

As the title says, my problem is that I don't know If/How I can use a String Resource in a String Resource in string.xml.

```
<string name="projectname">Include Test</string>
<string name="about">@string/projectname is to test if you can use a String Resource in a String Resource</string>
```

My question is if anyone knows if I can write

```
<string name="identifier">@string/other_identifier</string>
```

because Eclispe says

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'other_identifier' with value '@string/other_identifier eingeben...').
```

Comment: This question is really a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722374/android-how-to-inject-a-string-element-into-another-string-element-in-xml), and its accepted answer seems to be the best approach. Thanks to @Brian for pointing this out,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off constructing these `String`s at runtime. Combine different `String` resources together with the help of `String.format`.

Further details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: But with String.format and combining the Stings at runtimeI have the problem that I want to use it in an help text. But if I want to write `<string name="help4a_function">To use the function "@sting/a_function" you need to ...</string>` I have to make 2 items `"<string name="help4a_function_1">To use the function </string>` and `<string name="help4a_function_2"> you need to ...</string>` and combine them with the contents of `@sting/a_function`. If I'm wrong please correct me!

Comment: You would have a string such as: `<string name="help4a_function"> To use the function %1$s you need to ... </string>` and assign the name of the function using `String.format`.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. hopefully such a function will be added soon!

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Actually [this solution, using custom `ENTITY` entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3722882/786434) is much nicer.

---

The following should work out of the box:

```xml
<string name="identifier">@string/other_identifier</string>
```

I just tried it with API Level 8 and it works fine. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6378421/786434

To be able to cross-reference strings within other words, you can create yourself a small helper method:

```java
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@string/(\\S+)");

public static String getString(Resources res, int stringID) {
String s = res.getString(stringID);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    try {
    final Field f = R.string.class.getDeclaredField(matcher.group(1));
    final int id = f.getInt(null);
    final String replace = res.getString(id);
    s = s.replaceAll(matcher.group(), replace);

    } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignore) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignore) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ignore) {
    }
}

return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to insert a frequently used string (e.g. app name) in xml without using Java code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33252930/4665578):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources [
<!ENTITY appname "MyAppName">
<!ENTITY author "MrGreen">
]>

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">&appname;</string>
    <string name="description">The &appname; app was created by &author;</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :) Not natively though, but you can use this small library that allows you to resolve these placeholders at buildtime, so you won't have to add any Java/Kotlin code to make it work.

Based on your example, you'd have to set up your strings like this:

```
<string name="projectname">Include Test</string>
<string name="about">${projectname} is to test if you can use a String Resource in a String Resource</string>
```

And then the plugin will take care of creating the following:

```
<!-- Auto generated during compilation -->
<string name="about">Include Test is to test if you can use a String Resource in a String Resource</string>
```

More info here: https://github.com/LikeTheSalad/android-stem

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library.