# Android: How to refer to strings in a string definition

Tags: android, string

Is there anyone knows how to refer to a defined string in a string definition, i.e.:

```
<string name="string_1">I am string 1</string>
```

and then,

```
<string name="string_2">I want to refer to @string/string_1</string>
<string name="string_3">@string/string_1 need to be referred here</string>
```

I've tried the sample codes, but it didn't work!

Comment: you can't reference another item within another item.

Comment: Best is to do this in the code itself.

Comment: Possible [duplicate1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746058/reference-one-string-from-another-string-in-strings-xml), [duplicate2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722374/android-how-to-inject-a-string-element-into-another-string-element-in-xml)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using [`String.format()`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html):

```
<string name="string1">I am %1$s</string>
<string name="string2">String 1</string>

...
String string1 = String.format(resources.getString(R.string.string1, R.string.string2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it at one condition as long as you reference the entire string

```
<string name="string_1">I am string 1</string>
<string name="string_2">I am string 2</string>
```

and then,

```
<string name="string_2">@string/string_1</string>
<string name="string_3">@string/string_2</string>

<string name="string_default">@string/string2</string>
```

but following is not supported

```
<string name="string_default">@string/string1 TEST</string>
```

You can also get your issue resolved by using `String.format()` (a good walk around)