# how to add @string inside html paragraph?

Tags: android, html, textview

I am trying to put `@string/string_b` inside html `<p></p>`. For example,

```
<string name="string_a">very long text</string>

<string name="string_b">
     <![CDATA[
        <body>
            <p>This is string B</p>
            <p>@string/string_a</p>
            <p>Another string here</p>
        </body>
    ]]>
</string>
```

This will only shows:
This is string B
@string/string_a
Another string here

But I want to show:
This is string B
very long text.
Another string here

Btw, it will be displayed in [HtmlTextView](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview). If can, I want to make it inside xml only. Thank you guys!

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes but in another way. By extending HtmlTextView. Thanks btw.

Comment: No problem, post your answer yourself then, so if others have the same issue, they can see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make this change in your `strings.xml`:

```
 <string name="string_b">
         <![CDATA[
            <body>
                <p>This is string B</p>
                <p>%1$s</p>
                <p>Another string here</p>
            </body>
        ]]>
    </string>
```

Now in you Java code you can do this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String string_a = res.getString(R.string.string_a);
String string_b = String.format(res.getString(R.string.string_b), string_a);
```

Upon your request to do it solely in the xml, I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722374/android-how-to-inject-a-string-element-into-another-string-element-in-xml) that refers to the same thing. So you can take a look at the answer given there and see if it works for you.

Comment: is it possible to make it only in xml?

Comment: Take a look at the question and the answer to it, the one I linked in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. Hope it help others. Extending `HtmlTextView` gives us opportunity to add new attribute with `string` format. Then, `android:text` and `custom:text2` can be concatenated programatically inside custom `HtmlTextView`.

**1. Extend HtmlTextView**
or TextView if you are using it.

```
public class HtmlTextview extends HtmlTextView {
    public HtmlTextview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HtmlTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupText(attrs);
    }

    public HtmlTextview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setupText(attrs);
    }

    private void setupText(AttributeSet attrs) {

        String htmlString = (String) this.getText();
        String text2;

        TypedArray attributeValuesArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.concatenate, 0, 0);
        try{
            text2 = attributeValuesArray.getString(R.styleable.concatenate_text2);
        } finally {
            attributeValuesArray.recycle();
        }

        if(text2 != null && text2.length() > 0){
            htmlString = htmlString + text2;
            this.setHtmlFromString(htmlString, new HtmlTextView.RemoteImageGetter());
        }
    }
}
```

**2. HtmlTextview attributes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="concatenate">
        <attr name="text2" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

**3. In string.xml resources**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">HtmlTry</string>

    <string name="string_a">
        <![CDATA[
        <body>
            <p>very long text. Can also formatted in <font color="#f44336">Html.</font></p>
        </body>
        ]]>
    </string>

    <string name="string_b">
        <![CDATA[
        <body>
            <p>This is string B</p>
        </body>
        ]]>
    </string>

</resources>
```

**4. Lastly** apply it inside xml layout.

```
<com.htmltry.HtmlTextview
   android:id="@+id/tv"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/string_b"
   custom:text2="@string/string_a"
/>
```

and the final result is:
[image]