# String formatting via xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, string-formatting

I have string resource like

`<string name="my_string">Чек от %1$d до 2000 рублей</string>`

and I use this string in the `TextView` and need to put default values on the view initialization . So, I know, what I can make it with `context.getString(R.string.my_string, 100)`. But, I want to make it in the `TextView` xml definition.

Is there a way to use string formatting in `TextView` xml? Something like

`android:text="@string/my_string{100}"`

Comment: 100 is a number that replace %1$d in `my_string`

Answer (score 2):

You can't put formatting arguments in XML, only in Java code.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923874/use-string-format-arguments-in-android-layout-xml-file)

Comment: Oh, I try to find my quetion on SO, but I did not find your link. I marked my question as dublicate. Thanks!