# How do I use databinding to combine a string from resources with a dynamic variable in XML?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I  have a TextView which has a hardcoded string and I have a dynamic variable that I want to put at the end of this string. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PeopleName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/Generic_Text"+"@{ Profile.name }" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I am having an issue with  `android:text="@string/Generic_Text"+"@{ Profile.name }"` . The `Generic_Text` states " My Name is " then the `Profile.name` is dynamic and obviously changes from profile to profile. I want it so that the whole TextView output is **My Name is {Profile.name}**. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you using databinding?

Comment: Yes I am using databinding

Comment: Add your current java code as well please.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

You can do this:

```
android:text= "@{String.format(@string/Generic_Text, Profile.name)}"
```

if you use string formatting for your `Generic_Text` string. ex. `%s` at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot I just put that in and it worked correctly

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer, as this actually doesn't use Data bindings features to manipulate the text.

Comment: agree with @Darwind, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58095355/168435) for a working implementation with Binding Adapters

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky this answer is over 3 years old but definitely used to work before - do you recall what went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: Android studio does not offer intelisense with this. Is it normal or I have an issue with mine ?

Answer (score 433):

You can do this even simplier:

```
android:text= "@{@string/generic_text(profile.name)}"
```

you string should be like this:

```
<string name="generic_text">My Name is %s</string>
```

Edit:

1. Of course you can use as many variables as you need:

   ```
   android:text= "@{@string/generic_text(profile.firstName, profile.secondName)}"

   <string name="generic_text">My Name is %1$s %2$s</string>
   ```
2. It works just because it's designed in data binding. More in docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#resources

Comment: but it shows `My Name is null` if data isn't ready yet (e.g. wasn't loaded from network)

Comment: In this case just check it before. `android:text= "@{profile == null ? @string/loading : @string/generic_text(profile.firstName, profile.secondName)}"`

Comment: The best answer :)

Comment: Android studio does not offer intelisense with this. Is it normal or I have an issue with mine ?

Answer (score 93):

## Many ways to concat strings

#### 1. Using string resource (**Recommended because Localization**)

`android:text= "@{@string/generic_name(user.name)}"`

Just make string resource like this.

```
<string name="generic_name">Hello %s</string>
```

#### 2. Hard coded concat

```
android:text="@{`Hello ` + user.name}"/>
```

This is useful when you need hardcoded append like + for phone number.

#### 3. Using `String`'s concat method

```
android:text="@{user.firstName.concat(@string/space).concat(user.lastName)}"
```

Here `space` is an html entity which is placed inside `strings.xml`. Because `XML` does not accept Html entities or special characters directly. [(Link Html Entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50397301/6891563)

```
<string name="space">\u0020</string>
```

#### 4. Using `String.format()`

```
android:text= "@{String.format(@string/Hello, user.name)}"
```

you have to import String class in layout in this type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="String" />
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:text= "@{String.format(@string/Hello, user.name)}"
        ... >
    </TextView>
</layout>
```

#### 5. concat two strings by string resource.

```
android:text="@{@string/generic_name(user.firstName,user.lastName)}"
```

In this case put a string resource in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="generic_name">%1$s, %2$s</string>
```

**There can be many other ways, choose one you need.**

Comment: I get the error "cannot find identifiert format"

Answer (score 12):

strings.xml: `<string name="my_string">Hello %s</string>`

view.xml: `android:text="@{@string/my_string(name)}"`

Comment: As supportive information, it requires data binding enabled in gradle and a layout tag as a root tag in the view.xml.

Answer (score 9):

Use a [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

This sample is written in Kotlin and takes into account that the bound variable can be null:

```
@BindingAdapter("my_name")
fun TextView.setMyName(name: String?) {
    this.text =
        if (name.isNullOrEmpty()) "" else "${this.context.getString(R.string.Generic_Text)} $name"
}
```

then use the binding adapter in your XML instead of the `android:text` property

```
app:my_name="@{Profile.name}"
```

Comment: Been having a lot of trouble calling imported functions in the binding, this answer works perfectly for me and allows me to reuse my extensions.  Thanks!

Comment: Since, basic manipulation is already provided by `String` class from `xml`, this solution is only good to be used for advanced String manipulations based on your requirements. However, it is not incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

**2019 Update, Android studio to 3.4, Android Gradle Plugin to 3.4**

No more required to import

```
<import type="java.lang.String" />"
```

for string operations. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777289/5529263).

Answer (score 7):

In case if you want to **type text** in XML, you can use **``** quotation.

```
android:text="@{`Device Name`}"
```

elsewhere you need to **Concat with the String or variable**, you can use

```
android:text="@{`Device Name`.concat(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)}"
```

if you want to **Concat string resource** instead of the variable you can do,

```
android:text="@{@string/app_name.concat(`Device Name`)}"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also set string resource as parameter to other string resource using formatter like below:

```
<string name="first_param_text">Hello</string>
<string name="second_param_text">World</string>
<string name="formatted_text">%s lovely %s</string>
```

and

```
android:text="@{String.format(@string/formatted_text, @string/first_param_text, @string/second_param_text)}"
```

"Hello lovely World" will appear on the view.

Answer (score 2):

Just using `+` operator works for me:

```
android:text= "@{@string/Generic_Text +' '+ Profile.name)}"
```

String.xml will be:

```
<string name="Generic_Text">Hello</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you **can't** change the resource string to contain `%s` at the end (eg. because it's used elsewhere without the suffix):

```
android:text="@{@string/Generic_Text.concat(Profile.name)}"
```

If `Profile.name` can't be null, that's enough. However, if a `null` happens, it'll crash. You have to add another layer:

```
android:text="@{@string/Generic_Text.concat(Objects.toString(Profile.name))}"
```

(which requires `<import type="java.util.Objects"/>` to work.)

Again: all this extra work is worth it only if you have the resource string used elsewhere. The second reason is when you want to handle `null` as "empty string" instead of a "null" literal.

Comment: If the string resource is used elsewhere, why not just make a new resource?

Answer (score 1):

if you search one way to set your text with DataBinding when you have a string.xml like that

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="your_string_name"><![CDATA[<b>Name: </b>%s]]</string>
```

this @BindingAdapter can help you

**BindingAdapters.kt**

```
@BindingAdapter("spannedText")
fun TextView.setSpannedTextAdapter(formated: String) {
    text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(formated, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
}
```

**TextView atribute in your XML layout**

```
app:spannedText="@{@string/your_string_name(`Hello World!`)}"
```

**Output**

> **Name:** Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

just put or append your string resource name it will work fine

e.x  @string/test

android:text="@{@string/test+viewModel.name+@string/test}"

Answer (score 0):

yourViewBinding.yourTextView.setText(this.yourViewBinding.getRoot().getResources().getString(R.string.your_string) + yourStringVariable);