# How to overcome issues with implementing String Resource DataBinding

Tags: android-xml, android-resources, android-databinding

I'm having an issue with databinding. I'm trying to include an XML layout setting the **`tag`** of the included **`TextView`**. However, it resolves to the the included layout's name prefixed by layout and suffixed by _0 i.e.**`layout/common_helpinfo_0`**

In the main layout I have :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ....
        <LinearLayout
            .....
            >
            <TextView
                .... />
            <include layout="@layout/common_helpinfo"
                android:id="@+id/hi_tag_world1"
                app:tagstr="@{@string/hi_tag_world1}"
                >
            </include>
        </LinearLayout>
        ....
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The included layout `common_helpinfo` is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="tagstr" type="String"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        ....
        android:tag="@{tagstr}"
        ''''
        android:onClick="clickHelpInfo"
        >
    </TextView>
</layout>
```

To test this I have the following in my `MainActivity` :-

```
     public void clickHelpInfo(View v) {
        String hicaller = v.getTag().toString();
        int vid = v.getId();

        Toast.makeText(this,"You Clicked Help from button=" + hicaller + " ID+" + Integer.toString(vid)
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In the main layout I also have, a hard-coded equivalent of the included TextView:-

```
        <TextView
            ....
            android:tag="@string/hi_tag_world1"
            ''''
            android:onClick="clickHelpInfo"
            >
        </TextView>
```

And this works as expected, with the Toast displaying the contents of the String Resource **`hi_tag_world1`**.

In **`ActivitMainBinding`**, after a successful compile, I have the following which appears to show where the incorrect data is being set (***note I've actually included the common_helpinfo twice both act the same***) :-

```
private static final android.util.SparseIntArray sViewsWithIds;
static {
    sIncludes = new android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts(12);
    sIncludes.setIncludes(1, 
        new String[] {"common_helpinfo"}, <<<<<
        new int[] {3},
        new int[] {R.layout.common_helpinfo}); <<<<<
    sIncludes.setIncludes(2, 
        new String[] {"common_helpinfo"}, <<<<<
        new int[] {4},
        new int[] {R.layout.common_helpinfo}); <<<<<
    sViewsWithIds = new android.util.SparseIntArray();
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.vtext01, 5);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.vtext02, 6);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.vtext03, 7);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.tvhi03, 8);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.etext01, 9);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.actvemail, 10);
    sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.lvemail, 11);
}
```

However later in **`ActivityMainBinding`** I get the following which appears to try to get the correct data :-

```
@Override
protected void executeBindings() {
    long dirtyFlags = 0;
    synchronized(this) {
        dirtyFlags = mDirtyFlags;
        mDirtyFlags = 0;
    }
    // batch finished
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x4L) != 0) {
        // api target 1

        this.hiTagWorld1.setTagstr(getRoot().getResources().getString(R.string.hi_tag_world1));
        this.hiTagWorld2.setTagstr(getRoot().getResources().getString(R.string.hi_tag_world2));
    }
    executeBindingsOn(hiTagWorld1);
    executeBindingsOn(hiTagWorld2);
}
```

I've looked at and based my code on [How do I use databinding to combine a string from resources with a dynamic variable in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978499/how-do-i-use-databinding-to-combine-a-string-from-resources-with-a-dynamic-varia)

I've read through [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

I've turned on DataBinding and have build.gradle as :-

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mjt.testvcsuse"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair bit of playing around, I appear to have found a solution and that is to use the `dataBindingUtil`'s `setContentView` method to replace the `setContentView` method.

e.g. **`final ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);`**

i.e. Instead of :-

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ....
    }
```

The binding worked using :-

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
        ....
    }
```

I found this by reading this article [Android Authority - Data Binding in Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/data-binding-in-android-709747/), written by **Obaro Ogbo**. The relevant extract being :-

> **Data Binding Activity**
>
> At the moment, we have a layout file that is data binding capable.
>   However, to utilize its data binding ability, we have to load it in a
>   different way.
>
> Previously, you would load your layout like this:
>
> ```
> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
> final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
> button.setOnClickListener(...);
> ```
>
> With data binding, a Binding class is auto generated from your layout
>   file. The class is named using your layout file name by default. The
>   default name is generated by capitalizing the first letter of each
>   word after an underscore, removing all underscores, and adding
>   ‘Binding’ to the name. As such, activity_main.xml will result in a
>   class called ActivityMainBinding.
>   To associate this auto generated binding class in your code, you
>   invoke DataBindingUtil’s setContentView
>
> ```
> final ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
>     this, R.layout.activity_main);
> activityMainBinding.updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view) {
>         activityMainBinding.textView1.setText(R.string.text1b);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> In the code snippet above, you will notice that we can access the
>   updateButton Button directly. All views with an ‘@+id’ in a data
>   binding layout are automatically assigned to a final field of the
>   correct type. So Button updateButton is created for the layout Button
>   with ‘@+id/updateButton’, and TextView textView1 is created for the
>   id/text_view1 TextView.

*It doesn't appear to interfere with existing Views e.g. the non-data bound/hard coded TextView onClick handling still works with no other code changes.*