# Android data binding "Missing import expression although it is registered" after upgrade to gradle 5.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, androidx

After I upgrade my Android studio to 3.4, Android Gradle Plugin to 3.4 and gradle to 5.1.1

I got the data binding errors like below

I have made sure I cleaned project and rebuild, I have cleared cache and restarted AS.

This issue never happened before the upgrade

I can confirm it is because of the new gradle update

> **DataBinderMapperImpl.java:54: error: cannot find symbol**
>
> **e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Missing import expression although it is registered**

I found the solution:
Solution:

1. Now 3.4.1 released, use 3.4.1
2. Remove all import type in layout XML
3. Remove all string from import type in layout XML
4. Remove all integer from import type in layout XML

Comment: I assume you are using gradle plugin version 3.4 (not 4.3 as you mentioned in question).

Comment: @RanjanKumar Yes, fixed typo

Answer (score 98, accepted):

After I upgraded my Android studio and gradle plugin, I ran into similar issue because of the below line.
I was using this `<import type="java.lang.String" />` in my layout file.
Removing this import solved the issue.

> [Just as in managed code, java.lang.* is imported automatically.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes)

Comment: yes, you are right, I added a redundant Integer import made it failed.

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine for me. I just remove `<import type="java.lang.Integer"` in my layout file.

Comment: Please share the code or if possible the demo project

Comment: it works but if I am using android.text.TextUtils and remove it, it again throws the same error? How can I use it then? Any idea?

Comment: @Gautam I didn't get you. I am still able to use  
<import type="android.text.TextUtils" />

Comment: oh & I am unable to only for the TextUtils. If I remove this import, error says missing import

Comment: clean + rebuild!

Comment: Same problem here but I didn't need to clean/rebuild

Comment: How about "<import type="java.lang.Double" />"?

Answer (score 4):

I also face these errors in data binding. I tried with 'android.databinding.enableV2=true', it is not working. After I redo databinding for a layout.xml, I found these solutions.
if I'm using 'android.view.View' in layout.xml, I did import View and declare variable like this,

```
<data>
    <import type="java.util.List" />        
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <import type="com.example.android.mobilepos.data.pojos.ActionData" />
    <variable
        name="view"
        type="View" />
    <variable  name="actionList"  type="java.util.List&lt;com.example.android.mobilepos.data.pojos.ActionData>" />
```

And used variable view in like this.

```
 <EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:id="@+id/txt_payment_remark"                           
   android:hint="@string/hint_payment_remark"                            
   android:visibility="@{switch1.checked ? view.VISIBLE : view.GONE}" />
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/action_data_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color_white"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:actionSource="@{actionList}"
              app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
                tools:context=".ui.fragments.NewInvoiceFragment"
                tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_new_invoice">
```

I also did for Integer.toString() feature like this, but can't import and use Integer in layout.xml. So I shift Integer value to strings.xml with %d label.

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/txt_qty"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
     android:hint="@string/hint_quantity"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:maxLength="5"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:text="@{@string/shipment_qty(product.qty)}"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textColor="@color/black"
     android:textStyle="bold"                        
     tools:text="1000" />
```

I hope these will solve your problems.

Comment: I have 50 activities, how can I tell if any of them having this problem....

Comment: After Rebuild Project or double click Gradle ->ProjectName->app->other->assembleDebug in right-side panel, you will see error layout xml files.

Comment: rebuild project doesn't tell me anything for xml. gradle ->assembleDebug doesn't have a right side panel.....

Comment: First, Invalidate Caches / Restart.. and disable android.enableBuildCache=true and org.gradle.caching=true if you are enabled in gradle.properties. And then Clean and Rebuilt project.

Comment: How about <import type="java.lang.Double" />?

Comment: You don't need to import Double. You can use it directly, like this Double.toString(1000.00);

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using gradle plugin version 3.4 (not 4.3 as you mentioned in question).  See the list of available gradle-plugin version
 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle.                 There is change in data binding compiler option                                                  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#preview-compiler

To enable the new data binding compiler, add the following option to your gradle.properties file:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```