# Android how to use a string variable inside a textview with data binding

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

Good day, I am practising my skills using layout, just learned data binding, and I want to know how I can use a variable like defaultName within a textview, so I am trying to do this:

```
android:text="@={`hi `+ myName.defaultName}"
```

I want the output to be:

```
hi Travis Scott
```

But instead I get a nasty error which is this:

```
cannot find symbol class ActivityMainBindingImpl
import com.example.nickname.databinding.ActivityMainBindingImpl;
[databinding] {"msg":"The expression \u0027(\"hi \") + (myNameDefaultName)\u0027 cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding\n\nDetails: Two-way binding with string concatenation operator (+) only supports the empty string constant (`` or \"\")","file":"app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_main.xml","pos":[{"line0":27,"col0":25,"line1":27,"col1":49}]}
                                       ^
```

I researched the error, I didn't find the solution. I researched what alternatives people have used to this problem and I didn't find anything. The only thing I found was this "@={`hi` + myName.defaultName}" and that's it.

Comment: My working code is `android:text='@{"Search " + model.dailogBean.title}'`.

Comment: I just tried that, I replaced "text" with "hint" and still the same error

Comment: I was using for hint property, you can use for text property

Comment: Your exact answer `android:text='@{"hi " + myName.defaultName}'`

Comment: Yes, myName is the model in this case, and defaultName is a string

Comment: is `defaultName`  a LiveData??

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use databinding to combine a string from resources with a dynamic variable in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978499/how-do-i-use-databinding-to-combine-a-string-from-resources-with-a-dynamic-varia)

Comment: How the `TextView` value gonna change? It's value gets updated only when you set the text by calling `setText`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to two-way binding instead of one-way binding. Just remove "=" sign and change braskets

```
android:text='@{"hi" + item.title}'
```

Comment: Goodness, that solved the issue. I got rid of the "=" and it worked. Now it says exactly what I need it to say, thank you so much!